# How to create a custom Python code library for the Robot Framework

Tags: libraries, robotframework

I already have Python source files for some custom tasks. Can I create a custom library of these tasks as keywords and use in the Robot Framework?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is all documented fairly extensively in the Robot Framework user guide, in the section titled *[Creating test libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries)*.

You have a couple of choices. You can use your module directly, which makes every method in the module available as a keyword. This is probably not what you want since the library probably wasn't designed to be used as a collection of keywords. Your second choice is to create a new library that imports your modules, and your new library provides keywords that call the functions in the other library.

As a simple example, let's say you have a module named `MyLibrary.py` with the following contents:

```
def join_two_strings(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + " " + arg2
```

You can use this directly in a test suite as in the following example, assuming that `MyLibrary.py` is in the same folder as the suite, or is in a folder in your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | MyLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***
| Example that calls a Python keyword
| | ${result}= | join two strings | hello | world
| | Should be equal | ${result} | hello world
```

Comment: Hello, in that case, where to put MyLibrary.py file?

Comment: I put mine in a Resources subdirectory and give the relative path to MyLibrary.py in the Settings as in:
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections
Library  Resources/MyLibrary.py
Also note that as @Bryan showed above the Python underscores can be replaced with the more Robot Framework style spaces.