# How to get the error message in robot framework?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, report, robotframework

I have created a script to get the error output

```
***Settings***
Resource           importsLib.robot
Suite Setup     Run Keywords
...             Initialize Test     AND
...             Register Keyword To Run On Failure    Failure Callback
Variables       OMG.yaml
```

and the keywords

```
***Keywords***
Failure Callback
     Capture Page Screenshot
     Log Source    loglevel=WARN
```

but the point is I need to get HTML error message when Back-end didn't send the value to Front-end element sometimes and I need to track the root causes of faults or problems.

Can you offer the best solution for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpLibrary](http://peritus.github.io/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html) but you should also code BE tests for it, there is no way to check it under your FE tests if you are not check parallelly BE http methods.

You can create your own custom libraries or keywords for it.

And here is a example of how you can use custom libraries on the Robot Framework : 
[How to create a custom Python code library for the Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039016/how-to-create-a-custom-python-code-library-for-the-robot-framework)

Comment: It doesn't work for me because I don't want to test API, I want to get a log error message when The FE has found some error message on the Website.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the solution because it is work for your issue if we are talking about the issue you mentioned before, You will get all html response and you will be able to compare them with FE validations if you set your structure as I mentioned.

Comment: No it is about your code base, you should perform 2 different tests. First one will perform api events same as FE and the second one perform UI tests. Finally, You will be get 2 different datas from your test, one comes from BE api response, the other one will come from FE tests. Then you will compare them with custom method which created from you. @Phatto